# Want to target specific posts in a loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress site has a loop that creates posts, and I want to target specific posts to change their css values.

html - index.php

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
      get_template_part( 'content' );
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

content.php

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
$thumbnail_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'my-fun-size' );
$thumbnail_url = $thumbnail_data[0];
}
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?> >

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-cell">
   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   <?php the_category(', '); ?>
  </div>   
 </div>

</article><!-- /#post -->
```

It was suggested that I use 'get_post_meta ...' but I am not familiar with how to use it. I just want to change css values (padding, font-size, etc) for different posts

Comment: Do you want to target a specific post #, or are you trying to target a pattern  (i.e. Every odd or even post)?

Comment: Why you don't use "post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"  id ? Every post will have an Id and it will never change. Use code some think like #post-1234 { color: green; }

Comment: will it spit out #post-1, #post-2, etc? and where would I put that piece of code?

Comment: and although pretty much i'll be applying different effects to every second post (align-left, align-right, along-left, etc) It would be perhaps useful down the road to apply individual styles to eau post separately

Comment: also, if I use the "post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" id, every time I edit the post (remove one or change one) it spits out a new number id. Currently I have 5 posts, but I've been removing and editing them so much that they have 'post-107, etc' as outputs. Can I reset that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Custom Fields for this, so that you can define the values in the post itself, as opposed to having to edit the code every time you add a new post.

In the post, make sure you have Custom Fields visible (Togglable from screen options at the top)

Then make a field called "Alignment" or whatever you prefer and assign a value to it. (for example 'left')

[image: Custom Field example]

Then you can add a conditional in the loop.

```
<?php $alignment = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'Alignment',true);
if($alignment) == 'left'):?>
    <p>Do stuff and things here...</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

You can read more about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Hopefully that will work for you. If you want to get fancier with it, I would suggest looking at the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, which allows a lot more flexibility and options.

EDIT from comments:

1st option:
Set a field of "ExtraCSS" to "color:green;"
[image]

```
<?php $extraCSS = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'ExtraCSS',true);?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>'); <?php echo $extraCSS;?>" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?> >
```

2nd option:

(In your stylesheet:)

```
article:nth-child(2n+0)
{
    color:green;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: but won't that code make the field 'alignment' apply to all posts? since it's a loop that creates the post. If I have 7 posts i'll need 7 conditions then? As well when I put in your code ( I replaced 'text-cell' div with your code and put title and category where you put <p>Do stuff ....) it throws a syntax error message - syntax error, unexpected '=='

Comment: Yes, assuming you place that code withn the while loop, it will grab the "Alignment" set on that specific post, which you can do whatever with. You would need seven conditions if you plan to handle every singe post a different way. BUT, you could also get fancier with this and echo out each value and store CSS or HTML tags within it if you wanted. If your looking for something more procedural, that handles itself, you may want to do something in the CSS like :nth-child. I'll edit the post to see if that helps.

Comment: I have managed to target them using their 'post-<?php the_ID(); ?>' and it should work to my needs. The problem is that they spit out 'post-109  and post-107, etc in no order' I would like them to be like 'post-1, post-2, etc' Is there any way to reset the post ID to start at 1?

Comment: using the id seems easier since I can just do it all in css, it seems easier since all i'm doing is changing css, I don't need it to really do stuff other than change css values

Comment: Unfortunatly, changing the post IDs is a lot harder, since it more involved the Wordpress database. if your just adding targeted styling, you should try using the Custom Fields and have them store CSS styling, then echo it in where you need it. (option 1)

Comment: K, added your code to the post, how can I control the field in my css? if that is in my post then all posts will have colour-green

Comment: I have around 5-7 posts and mostly each needs it's own custom css, will I just copy that '<?php $extraCSS = ... ' seven times in a row with different values and which ever one is in the post will be applied and the others ignored?

Comment: Assuming your going with the first option, it should only grab the CSS value you added in the individual post. (For example you could set post 3 to say 'color:red;') and then it would output red for that specific post. if you dont enter a value at all, it won't affect the color of that post at all.

Comment: No, you only need the line once. since it's in a loop, it will generate it based off the post. (much like $thumbnail_url = $thumbnail_data[0];) I added a picture that will hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: oh ok, now is there a way to link the 'value' in the post to my css? For example set field to 'ExtraCSS' then set value to 'post1' then in my css document I can use .post1 { text-align: right; padding: 10px; etc... } then in another post I set value to 'post2' and then in css  .post2 { etc } ?

Comment: Yeah, definately. I would argue that that might be better handled on the post itself, but if you just move <?php echo $extraCSS;?> to class="<?php echo $extraCSS;?>" that should work. or you could put it in the ID as well instead of id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" have id="post-<?php <?php echo $extraCSS;?>" EDIT: if you want to use it as a class: <?php post_class('container-fluid', $extraCSS); ?> should work. sorry.

Comment: she works! Visually the same as I had, but this way does seem more 'cleaner' and shouldn't have to be edited when I change posts around Thank you my friend! Cheers!